# Check Daydream compatibility in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-vr, daydream

Let say I'm developing a Hybrid app that will lunch in VR mode if the device is `daydream` ready , other than that it will lunch normally .

```c#
void Start(){
    if(magical condition) {
        EnableVR (); 
    }
}

IEnumerator LoadDevice(string newDevice, bool enable)
{
    VRSettings.LoadDeviceByName(newDevice);
    yield return null;
    VRSettings.enabled = enable;
}

void EnableVR()
{
    StartCoroutine(LoadDevice("daydream", true));
}

void DisableVR()
{
    StartCoroutine(LoadDevice("", false));
}
```

how can I check if the current device is daydream device or not  ?

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/detecting-if-the-current-headset-is-daydream-or-cardboard.448938/) helps you

Answer (score 0):

Originating from [derHugo's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52147585/check-daydream-compatibility-in-unity#comment91254648_52147585), as the documentation links have changed due to a refactor on Unity's end from a `VR` namespace to `XR` (as it covers all of AR, VR, and MR):

[`XRSettings.loadedDeviceName.html`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/XR.XRSettings-loadedDeviceName.html) will tell you the type of device that's currently active.

[`XRDevice.model`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/XR.XRDevice-model.html) will let you know the specific model.

> **joejo**
>
> You need to check `VRSettings.loadedDeviceName` to see if the currently running device is "cardboard" or "daydream". That should let you know what device you are running on so you can make decisions about how to handle input.